# Redirecting My site from two domain's tlds causing a infinte redirect loop

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have a website named smarkmart. I want to redirect it in three ways.
 1. In india it should be on www.smarkmart.in
 2. In USA it should be on www.smarkmart.com 
 3. Rest of other it should be on www.smarkmart.com

Here is my code for redirection-

```
session_start();
require 'geoplugin.class.php';
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
if (isset($_SESSION['pricetype'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['pricetype']);
}
// create a variable for the country code
$var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
// redirect based on country code:
if (!isset($_SESSION['pricetype'])) {
    if ($var_country_code == "US") {
        header('Location: http://www.smarkmart.com');
        $_SESSION['pricetype'] = "priceinr";
    }
    if ($var_country_code == "IN") {
        header('Location: http://www.smarkmart.in');
        $_SESSION['pricetype'] = "priceusd";
    } else {
        header('Location: http://www.smarkmart.com');
        $_SESSION['pricetype'] = "priceinr";
    }
}
$pricetype = $_SESSION['pricetype'];
```

This is causing a infinte loop. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not SEO and user friendly. take a look at: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You redirect only if $_SESSION['pricetype'] is null but you unset it at the start of the script :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['pricetype']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['pricetype']);
}
```